# Made numeric decrement

Tags: php, numerical

anybody can help me me with this? I have a variable such:

```
$page = '50';
$newpage = 'http://www.mydomain.com/page/'.$page.'';

I want new page echo such this:
http://www.mydomain.com/page/50
http://www.mydomain.com/page/49
......
.......
....... until page acho such:
http://www.mydomain.com/page/1
```

Comment: Open your php documentation, see chapter about operators (and type casting if necessary) and loop. Or at least post what you have done.

Comment: This is... incredibly, incredibly basic [`for`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php) looping.

Comment: @KalpeshMehta What has C got to do with this?

Comment: If you can't do a basic `for` loop then you really need to start with some basic tutorials/a book.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
for($page=50;$page>0;$page--) {
    $newpage = 'http://www.mydomain.com/page/'.$page.'';
    echo "$newpage\n";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at this `for` loop:

```
$prefix = 'http://www.mydomain.com/page/';
for ($page = 50; $page >= 1; $page--) {
    echo $prefix.$page;
}
```

First, the variable `$page` is initialized. I use `50` instead of `'50'` because we're dealing with numbers and not with strings.

The next bit is the condition while the loop continues: `$page >= 1` - so the loop will stop after `1`.

The last part is a decrement operator, it subracts 1 off `$page` for each loop iteration.

Finally, the prefix and the page number are combined using the concat operator (`.`).

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is :

```
<?php
for($i=50; 0 <= $i; $i--){
    echo $i.'<br />';
}
?>
```

if you don't want to go upto 0, change `<=` for `<`. This will loop from 50 until 0 so it will eacho in order :

```
50
49
48
47
46
...
3
2
1
0
```

Here 50 is your start number, 0 is your last number to go. So in this example it print out 50 until 0.